# Prove $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that the function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $ has first-order partial derivatives and that the point $\mathbf x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is a local minimizer for $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $, meaning that there is a positive number $r$ such that $$f(\mathbf x + \mathbf h) \ge f(\mathbf x) \quad \text if \ dist(\mathbf x, \mathbf x + \mathbf h) \lt r. $$ 
Prove $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0.$ 
To show that $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$ is true, I need to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(\mathbf x) \ \forall n$ but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in\Bbb R^n$. The directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $h$
is
$$
D_v f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac 1h (f(x+hv)-f(x))
= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac 1h (\nabla f(x)\cdot (hv)+o(hv))
=\nabla f(x)\cdot v.
$$

As $f$ has a local minimum in $x$, the function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined as
$g(h) = f(x+hv)$ has a local minimum in $0$, hence  $g'(0)=0$.

But $$
g'(0) = D_v f(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot v.
$$As this is true for every $v\in\Bbb R^n$, $\nabla f(x)=0$.